# HTML inline image container size as position: relative

Tags: html, image, css

Usually, When there is an image in an inline element - span (for example) stretch to fit the image, no?
I'm trying to put an Absolute div on an image - easy. 
Problem starts when the image size is dynamic, and doesn't have a fix size.

I try avoiding Javascript. it must fit all browsers

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/15Ljkuuw/11/)

HTML and CSS:

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.realContainer {
  background-color: #efefef;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.realContainer .inlineContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.realContainer * {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.absoluteDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeSize()">changeSize</button>

<div class="bigContainer">
  <div class="realContainer">
    <span class="inlineContainer">
            <img src="https://openclipart.org/download/216413/coniglio_rabbit_small.svg" />
            <div class="absoluteDiv">
              XXX
            </div>
          </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I try to get the XXX (the absolute div) to be always top 50% and left 50% of the image. and the image has to fit the container and not stretch or cut.

Comment: The problem is the  `<span>` didn't stretch out as what you are expecting it to be. Add a background color to the  `<span>` and you'll see what I mean

Comment: yes, this is where the problem starts :) why ?

Answer (score 0):

Notice the:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

instead of (in your JSFiddle):

```
top: -50%;
left: 50%;
```

I tried to do what you described, please try it out
Basically I changed removed the position:relative from the inlineContainer in order to make sure your absoluteDiv is absolute to the realContainer instead:

```css
body{
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}


.realContainer{
    background-color:#efefef;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.realContainer .inlineContainer{
}

.realContainer *{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}


.absoluteDiv{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    background-color:green;
    transition: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeSize()">changeSize</button>

<div class="bigContainer">
  <div class="realContainer">
    <span class="inlineContainer">
        <img src="https://openclipart.org/download/216413/coniglio_rabbit_small.svg" />
        <div class="absoluteDiv">XXX</div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another option is to change the inlineContainer to display:inline-block

```css
body{
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}


.realContainer{
    background-color:#efefef;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.realContainer .inlineContainer{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.realContainer *{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}


.absoluteDiv{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    background-color:green;
    transition: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeSize()">changeSize</button>

<div class="bigContainer">
  <div class="realContainer">
    <span class="inlineContainer">
        <img src="https://openclipart.org/download/216413/coniglio_rabbit_small.svg" />
        <div class="absoluteDiv">XXX</div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both examples are putting the XXX in the center of the container. what i need is to place the XXX at the center of the **image**.